# ansible + how to exclude the when in case hostname of machine is uniq

Tags: linux, rhel, ansible

the following ansible code meaning is to exit and send the message that we cant reboot when the machine is prod server

the production servers can identified by "prod" word in hostname of machine as

```
hostname

server109.prod.domain.com
```

but in case machine name include lab as the following

```
server109.lab.domain.com
```

then we not want to exit

```
- name: exit if reboot needed
  fail:
    msg: after kernel update need reboot but reboot will not be on production machines 
  when: res.reboot_required
```

so my question is how to update the "when" in case we not want to exit when machine name include "lab"

Comment: If the `ansible_hostname` field is populated correctly, you could use `when: res.reboot_required and 'prod' not in {{ ansible_hostname }}`

Comment: but in case I want to use the "lab" for exclude then how it will be?  ( because other server include not only prod or lab they have include other names as server12.maintence.domain.com etc

Comment: Then you use `'lab' in {{ ansible_hostname }}`. This is a boolean operation.

Answer (score 0):

According your example and Ansible [Discovering variables: facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) the [`ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) would be

```
ansible_hostname: "server109"
ansible_domain: "lab.domain.com"
```

therefore the [Conditional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) should be

```
when: (results.reboot_required) and (ansible_domain == "lab.domain.com")
```

or

```
when: (results.reboot_required) and ("lab" in ansible_domain)
```

Thanks to

- [How to get the first part of the `inventory_hostname` in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275537/)
- [What's the difference between `inventory_hostname` and `ansible_hostname`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908067/)
- [Run an Ansible task only when the hostname contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533372/)